# Can I hide a poor drywall patch with texture?

Tags: drywall, texture

I just patched a section for a beverage fridge and I realize I should have gotten the patch more level. Should it have been lower than the original walls so there's no lump? Will more texture hide the uneven patch? I am using an orange peel texture in a can.

[image]

Comment: Did you tape on top of the texture and then just fill in a deep space with mud?

Comment: Did you try one of those "California patches" that I've seen on YouTube? How did that patch get so out of level?

Comment: Instead of redoing everything right now, place some pictures/posters along the top, till you are ready to repaint.  It is just a cosmetic issue so repairing it can be done later.  Two or three pictures will hide it.

Comment: Did you spray the whole thing including the areas beyond your repair? If not, I'm quite surprised at how close the new texture is to matching the old!

Comment: Yeah, looks like what you did was level your patch to "height" of the adjacent "peaks" and then stack your texture onto that patch, so your new peaks are higher than your old peaks.  You needed to level your patch to the adjacent "valleys" before texturing.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, texture doesn't hide anything but the most fine flaws in drywall. It certainly doesn't reshape the surface. You don't need the patch *below* the surrounding area, but you need it flush and well tapered.

Here's what I'd do now.

1. Scrape away the texture (green area in the image below). Remove it from the left corner of the wall and between the fridge opening and the woodwork above. Remove the right side at a slant or curve up to the woodwork from the corner of the opening. (You don't want a vertical line to catch the eye.)
2. Sand lightly to completely remove the texture in that area. You can't effectively skim the patch with it bumpy.
3. Skim the patch edges with a wide knife pressed firmly (purple area). Your repair should be at least 10-12" wide, spanning from the high areas to the low.
4. Let that dry, then give it a light scrape with the knife to knock off any crumbs. Repeat the previous step.
5. Repeat the last two steps as necessary. When you think you're done, hold a strong light at a low angle to the wall and look for shadow indicating that you're *not* done. Repeat again as needed.
6. Do a final light sanding just to remove crusties, then vacuum to remove dust.
7. Reapply your texture, then prime and paint.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Texture as the fix? No way. If it was in the middle of a wide open wall, then the fix would be joint compound to feather the edges better and then retexture. That close to that upper trim and with the lump under the fridge's future trim, though, the fix is to cut it out and get it better leveled. It looks like your patch was the wrong thickness.

Comment: No need to cut this out. There's room in the critical areas to skim it out effectively.

Comment: @isherwood, there's no _need_ to do anything with it. The best finish possible for somebody at the OP's implied skill level is to cut it out and get the fill piece somewhat level with the wall.

Comment: It already was somewhat level. Most of what we see is a raised tape joint.